# How to fetch data (text) from an external website with PHP if possible?

Tags: php, text, preg-match, fetch, file-get-contents

I'm trying to extract data (text) from an external site and put it on my site.
I want to get football scores of an external site and put it on mine.
I've researched and found out I can do this using **Preg_Match** but i just can't seem to figure out how to extract data within html tags.

*For example*

this is the HTML structure of an external site.

```
<td valign="top" align="center" class="s1"><b>Text I Want To Fetch</b></td>
```

How would I fetch the text within tags? Would help me out allot! THANKS!

Comment: Use the [DOM library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), if you have any questions with this library, feel free to come back!

Comment: +1 for quick and helpful @DaveChen :)

Comment: i am a gigantic noob and need a solid example that's identical to my issue to understand. But thanks for the quick tip!

Comment: bet you a million dollars there are API's for this, stop doing things the hard way. and not that because its one some one else's site does not automatically give you the rights to use it on yours.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say but I am not stealing content. I just want to fetch some score data and show it on my site.

Comment: `fetch some score data and show it on my site` `not stealing content`

Comment: depending the the sport, even the scores can be licensed property.

Comment: Go ahead and post the website, we'll see if they have an API available, if not, you could ask them politely to create one.

Comment: http://voetbalzone.nl/

Answer (score 2):

You can get the content of a webpage by using file_get_contents method.

Eg:

$content = file_get_contents('http://www.source.com/page.html');

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

$html = '<td valign="top" align="center" class="s1"><b>Text I Want To Fetch</b></td>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td'); //find td
$dom = $dom->item(0);                    //traverse the first td
$dom = $dom->getElementsByTagName('b');  //find b
$dom = $dom->item(0);                    //traverse the first b
$dom = $dom->textContent;                //get text

var_dump($dom);                          //dump it, echo, or print
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/BuANQKZr)

In this example, there weren't any other `textContent`, so if your HTML only has text within bold, you may use this as well:

```
<?php

$html = '<td valign="top" align="center" class="s1"><b>Text I Want To Fetch</b></td>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom = $dom->textContent;

var_dump($dom);
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/P20xhlSm)

Comment: exactly what I need! How would I use this with an external site? Where do I say open this url?

Comment: I would listen to Dagon's comment. What is the website in question? If they don't provide an API, they probably don't want you to be doing this. And Stackoverflow is **not** the place to be asking these types of questions then.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about using php to fetch data, then file_get_contents(url) may help; however, you can fetch data using AJAX request with Jquery too. Down here is the link to AJAX documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/